# file upload in laravel

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel

I want to create a file upload in laravel.this is panel.blade.php:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'send-file','files'=>true)) }} 
{{ Form::label('file', 'File' ,array()) }}
{{ Form::file('file', '', array()) }}
{{ Form::submit('send') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

and this is routes.php:

```
Route::get('/panel/', function()
{
    return View::make('panel.index');
});
Route::get('/send-file', function()
{
    var_dump(Input::file('file'));
});
```

i call send-file by www.mysite.com/send-file and "Null" displayed.but when i want to ubload file in www.mysite.com/panel and send file to www.mysite.com/send-file error displayed.in the laravel log error this error displayed:

```
[2015-01-07 06:45:18] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException' in /var/www/usb/bootstrap/compiled.php:5750
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/usb/bootstrap/compiled.php(5746): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(Array)
#1 /var/www/usb/bootstrap/compiled.php(5724): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->getOtherMethodsRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Array)
#2 /var/www/usb/bootstrap/compiled.php(5048): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 /var/www/usb/bootstrap/compiled.php(5036): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 /var/www/usb/bootstrap/compiled.php(5028): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /var/www/usb/bootstrap/compiled.php(715): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 /var/www/usb/bootstrap/compiled.php(696): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 /var/www/usb/bootstrap/compiled.php(7800): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#8 /var/www/usb/bootstrap/compiled.php(8407): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#9 /var/www/usb/bootstrap/compiled.php(8354): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#10 /var/www/usb/bootstrap/compiled.php(11017): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#11 /var/www/usb/bootstrap/compiled.php(657): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 /var/www/usb/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#13 {main} [] []
```

I think this error is about httpd configuration.I put a .htaccess file in the root laravel root and this is the .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The method isn't GET, is the POST method, because you are sending data to PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're route needs to be a `POST` route:

```
Route::post('/send-file', function()
{
    var_dump(Input::file('file'));
});
```

Obviously file uploads don't work via GET. Also the default method for forms created with Laravels helper is POST.

By the way, the `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` usually means that a matching route is found (the URL is right) but the method is well... *not allowed*. So either your route has the wrong method or you try to access it with the wrong method.